# Jenkins Pipeline: how can I disable the current job from inside a pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Is there a way to disable a Jenkins job from inside a pipeline?
I use the Disable Failed Job plugin very heavily https://plugins.jenkins.io/disable-failed-job , so that when a Jenkins job fails, it is automatically disabled.
This is handy for the workflow that I have.

This plugin unfortunately does not work with Jenkins Pipeline.

Answer (score 3):

[Stuart Rowe](https://github.com/stuartrowe) helped me come up with the following:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('disable build') {
            steps {
                script {
                   // See:
                   //    https://ci.jenkins.io/pipeline-syntax/globals#currentBuild
                   //    https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-support/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/support/steps/build/RunWrapper.html
                   //    https://javadoc.jenkins.io/jenkins/model/ParameterizedJobMixIn.ParameterizedJob.html#setDisabled-boolean-

               currentBuild.rawBuild.getParent().setDisabled(true)

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting - does this require any special permissions or security settings?

Comment: @BitwiseMan It works perfectly, however you need admin approval to run the pipeline outside the groovy sandbox. See https://plugins.jenkins.io/script-security/ for more info.